# How can I see which applications eat up disk space?

Tags: internal-storage

[DiskUsage](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.diskusage) shows 189 Megs of used space, of which System data takes up 118 Megs.

How can I find what application are using the rest? I have Android 2.3.5.

Answer (score 5):

If you go to Settings > Apps, there will be a list of installed applications. If you press the menu button on that page, you can sort the applications by their size. Note that this size includes both the program files (APK) and stored data (databases, private saved files excluding those on SD card).

Comment: Just tested on 2.3.3, and there's the path is "home" -> "settings" -> "applications" -> "Storage Use".

Comment: To order by size, I had to press "home" twice since the presented option contains only one value at a time. The first tap presents "a-z" select it. The second tap brings up the "size" option select and your done.