# How to increase device's memory storage?

Tags: internal-storage

I have an ATT Samsung Galaxy Note. It keeps saying I have low memory, yet I have an external 32Gb SD card and there are 10GB on device left. I don't get why the system memory is being used up. I have 334Mb left and 1.89GB used.
Is there something that will fix this issue?

Comment: Possible Duplicates: [Phone memory full and it shouldn't be](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/21746/), [My internal storage capacity is running low, what can I do?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29416/); also refer to: [How can I see which applications eat up disk space?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/26405/)

Answer (score 1):

The system uses internal/device memory for a lot of things like...

- app data (`/data/data/*`)
- Dalvik cache (`/data/dalvik-cache`)
- Crash- and other system logs (`/data/anr`, `/data/dontpanic`, `/data/kernelpanics`, `/data/logger`, `/data/panicreports`, `/data/tombstones`)
- Misc. caches and temporary locations of Google Services (`/data/backup`, `/data/local`)
- Misc. system files (`/data/system`)
- Installed apps not on SD (`/data/app`)

and more. You can free some space by moving apps to sdcard (if the apps support this). On a rooted device, you might be able to move even more (e.g. Dalvik cache, app data). But you won't be able to move all.

You will not be able to "increase device's memory storage" -- all you can do is to increase free storage, not the absolute number. As we had this topic quite often, please see related questions for possible actions, e.g.:

- [Phone memory full and it shouldn't be](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/21746/16575)
- [My internal storage capacity is running low, what can I do?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29416/16575)
- [How can I see which applications eat up disk space?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/26405/16575)
- [What can I do to manage my phone's internal storage?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2065/16575)
- other questions from the "Related" section on this page

Answer (score 0):

May not be relevant now... but I needed it now and solved...
The link below solved my issue. No rooting or any hacking required. As it only clears the dump (log files etc.), very less risky.

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16818049/1161069

Here's a very simple solution that works on my Samsung Galaxy S II  and NOTE 1; I have no idea about other models:

1. Open the Phone app and switch to Keypad.
2. Dial *#9900#
3. On the screen that appears, click on the button labelled "Delete dumpstate/logcat".

I've restored about one GB of system space this way.