# Android HTC One SV App storage full of unknown data

Tags: internal-storage, htc, htc-one-s

I have an Android HTC One SV (Android 4.1.2, HTC Sense 5.0, not rooted). It's recently been struggling for storage space to the point where it was reporting low and then critically low storage. Note this is the *app* storage, not anything to do with the built-in or external SD cards.

> tl;dr: **Is there a known issue with "dead files" cluttering up App Storage? Is there any way to clear said storage out, or at least view the app storage and see what's taking up the space?**

---

Steps I took as space became more and more scarce:

- Moved apps that don't care about being on the App Storage to the SD Card
- Cleared all the caches I could find
- Cleared all the data I could find
- Deleted all text messages
- Moved apps that really don't like being on the SD Card to the SD card
- Uninstalled all uninstallable apps except the ones I was actually using on a daily basis
- Uninstalled updates to the non-uninstallable apps
- Uninstalled apps that were actually on the SD Card out of sheer desperation

Whatever space was regained by this was in the 10-50 megabyte range in total and was "mysteriously eaten" over about 2 weeks of normal usage (e.g. web-surfing on Chrome, checking e-mails). By the time I'd got to the bottom step, the automated storage tool was informing me that there was nothing to uninstall/move.

When the phone finally started reporting "less than 0Mb" and crashing the basic phone functionality, I took extreme measures and "Power+Vol'Down'd" it, selecting "Clear Storage" from the BootLoader. That got me back almost 1Gb of space, at which point I was finally able to install Android 4.2.2 (up to this point, it couldn't even *download* the necessary update). I also updated all the built-in applications to current.

I then installed my core application suite:

- Note Everything
- BeyondPod Pro
- NoteEverything Pro
- Amazon MP3
- Audible

My phone currently reports that it has 355MB of "App Storage" available; out of 3.85 Gb. Of the used, 673MB is Apps, and a staggering *2.85 Gb* is the mysterious "Other".

I want that **Other** back. The space reclamation tool merely suggests I uninstall the 5 apps above for a grand total of 66.7 Mb, which is... irritating.

Is there a known issue with "dead files" cluttering up App Storage? Is there any way to clear said storage out, or at least view the app storage and see what's taking up the space?

Comment: A couple of quick thoughts based on your comments:

-how much space are your amazon mp3s taking?
-the audible books?
-are you syncing a bunch of emails? some attachments can gobble up space
-web downloads? did you flush the chrome cache too (not that that will get you much, but just thinking aloud...)

Comment: @Lived: Effectively none to all of those (Haven't started the re-download process). But even then, the MP3's shouldn't be going to the *app* storage, surely?

Comment: @LivedWithOtters and yes, the Chrome cache and data were the first up against the wall.

Comment: Well, dang. Those were the easy ones.  Don't suppose you're rooted?

Comment: Nope, (see the parentheses at the top for my specs)

Comment: *slaps forehead* on the not-seeing-specs.  Here's a convoluted way: http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/android-hacking-security-part-14-examining-android-app-specific-data-non-rooted-devices/ which will give you a backdoor look without root but not for the faint-of-heart and maybe not exactly the area you're looking for.  I remember running across something the other day (my memory says it was for non-rooted), but I need to track it down...

Comment: "listed in *other*" and "issue with dead files" triggers something in me: it could be [tombstones](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=tombstones) (no joke: those are dumps of crashes). For some devices there are "secret codes" you can [execute from the dialer to clear them out](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/65295/16575), on rooted devices you can of course do that directly in the file-system. With both unavailable, I'm not sure what gets rid of them apart from a factory-reset.

Comment: Well, the new ridiculously expensive phone's turned up, so when I get the time, I might root this thing and see if I can get to the bottom of the issue. Thanks everyone for your advice!

Answer (score -1):

When I researched this same thing, all I came across pointed to that data being used for the HTC sense software along with other preinstalled apps.

Comment: Would that turn up as "other"? Being app-data, I'd expect it rather under "Apps".

Comment: Consider adding some reference links to the answer since we can't be sure what did you research on this same thing (and whether that supports the answer or not)